# Delphi: how to debug Windows Authentication related issues?

Tags: sql-server, delphi, windows-authentication, remote-debugging

I noticed a bug at customer side that I cannot reproduce. It is 99% linked to MS SQL Server  windows authentication.

How is it possible to debug an application when windows authentication is involved?

Is it possible (and if yes how) to use remote debugger (I never tried that)?

As an alternative I can do a special build that logs errors in a file.

Comment: Logging errors will be a good idea.

Comment: You need to log the error first.  Then, with that error message or exception stack trace, you can try to google or post it here.  Then, some people may be able to tell you where to look it.

Comment: It is always possibile to debug an application. But if the bug is outside the scope of your code you may have an hard time pinpointing it. Without any hint about the bug is impossible to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always log your errors with complete stack trace, to give you the idea exactly where the error happened. You can use something like MadExcept which enables the user to send you the error log with all relevant data appended when it happens.

When debugging windows API errors, the single relevant piece of information is the API return code that the API itself returns or you can get it via GetLastError function. Success is usually zero (but not always) and error some positive Integer (DWORD) code. Just look at MSDN what it means. You go on from there. I am pretty sure that just the return error code itself will give you enough info (along with your stack trace etc...) about what is wrong.

If not the more detailed analysis is needed. You can then try to replicate user enviromment or remote debug the app.

Oh and note that Windows APIs do not raise exceptions. You are responsible for checking the return code and raising the exception yourself if you feel the need to. It is an old style "C functional type" of programming.

EDIT:

If you are looking for a simple and free solution you can look at [SimpleLog](http://www.cromis.net/blog/downloads/simplelog/), a logging solution of my own. But MadExcept is way better and is full of different options.

Comment: madexcept is not free from comercial use. alternative is to use JCL http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help:Debugging.Stackinforoutines

Comment: If you are selling commercial software then you can afford madExcept!

Comment: I agree with David. It should be a minimal cost compared to the savings. If you want a simple and free solution you can look at my SimpleLog. It is based on JCL and simplifies things a log. But I did not want to write about it at first as MadExcept is way better. I will update the answer for those seeking free solution for commercial use. Even there (free code) I am sure better (richer) solutions exist, but I am not aware of any.

Comment: Ok i see, I will consider MadExcept. As you said it is a commercial application, it is way less expensive for me to buy MADExcept as David suggests. These kind of "blind bugs" are really a problem. I experience them from time to time and always I suffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use remote debugger to debug an application running on a different host than the IDE, but it requires:

- Remote debugger installed on the target machine
- A debug build and remote symbols on the target machine

If your customer allowd that remote debugger is an option. IMHO it is always a good idea to have some application switch (a command line parameter, a registry entry, etc.) that allows for loggin errors in detail when needed (beware of security, though).

Another options is to use OutputDebugStr and then use a tool like SysInternals' DebugView to get the output. There is also a unit to write output to SysInternal's Process Monitor.

Comment: +1 thanks for the informations. For sure remote debugger is overhead and the customer won't allow me easily to do something like that.